# Steady state of a dynamical equation

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, stochastic-processes

Suppose we have the following dynamical equation:

$P(k+1)=A\bigg(P(k) - P(k)H^T(k)\big(H(k)P(k)H^T(k)+Z\big)^{-1}H(k)P(k)\bigg)A^T+W$

with $P(0)=0$, where $P$, $A$, $H$, $Z$, $W$ are all $N\times N$ matrices, $A, Z, W$ are constant matrices. Each element of $H$ is standard Gaussian distributed. Using simulations, I founded out that there exists a steady state distribution for $P(k)$. Is it possible to calculated $\mathbb{E}[P(n)]=\overline{P}$, where $\overline{P}$ can in terms of a solution of a equation?